# Difference between COMPILE and COMPILE WITH DEBUG within Oracle Sql Dev?

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, compilation

I am new to Oracle SQL developer and I was just curious as to the difference between the COMPILE and COMPILE WITH DEBUG options.  Does this mean if a program unit is simply COMPILED, then I will not be able to debug it ?

What about in a production environment, where I want to run through the procedure (in debug mode) but without recompiling (in order to avoid invalidating other objects) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean if a program unit is simply COMPILED, then I will not be able to debug it ?

You're right.

> What about in a production environment, where I want to run through the procedure (in debug mode) but without recompiling (in order to avoid invalidating other objects) ?

Without recompiling a procedure for debug, debugging is not possible!

Comment: @Rik Garner: For single operations it is not important. But will you do mass-operations it is better to compile without debugging!